# only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays

Hei I am trying to get a plot for the following problem:
U (x) =U0, if |x| ≥ x0
U (x)=U0*|x|/x0 if |x| < x0

and programm:

```
from pylab import*
x_0=5
U_0=200
#U_x=zeros(n,1)
#x=zeros(n,1)
x=arange(-20,20,0.01)
if float(abs(x))>=x_0:
    U_x=U_0
elif float(abs(x))<x_0:
    U_x=U_0*(float(abs(x))/x_0)
fig=figure()
suptitle("a)") 
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plot(x,U_x)
xlabel('x [m]')
ylabel('U_x [J]')
show()
```

But I always get this mistake:

```
if float(abs(x))>=x_0:
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Please help:)

Comment: Your `x` is an array. `abs()` needs a scalar. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @9000: `abs()` doesn't need a scalar, it'll work on array operands; it's the `float()` which raises the exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

abs(x) is an array, you can't convert the array to a float value, that is the error. You can write a for loop to do the calculation, but numpy can do vectorized if condition by `numpy.where`. For more information, read the [document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-20, 20, 0.01)
x0 = 5
U0 = 200
u = np.where(np.abs(x) >= x0, U0, U0*np.abs(x)/x0)
plot(x, u, lw=3)
```

output:

[image]

You can also use [piecewise](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) function, it can deal with more complicated case.